# Valid orderings for topological sort

Tags: topological-ordering

I am reading *Algorithms* by Dasgupta et al and the graph section provides an example graph and mentions that there are 4 orderings with one of them being B, A, D, C, E, F.

[image: graph]

Are the other 3?

- B, A, D, C, F, E
- B, D, A, C, E, F
- B, D, A, C, F, E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *source* is a vertex with in-degree zero.

An order of the vertices is a *topological order* if deleting the vertices in that order deletes only *sources*.

Hence, you can verify that an order is topological by deleting one and one vertex, and never deleting a vertex with an in-edge.

Your answer is correct, the topological orders are `B,{A,D},C,{E,F}`, where you can choose the order inside the braces, i.e., there are four of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can answer your own question by checking whether, for each edge $(u,v)$ of the graph, $u$ appears before $v$ in each of the three candidate topological orders that you listed.

Comment: What do you mean by **candidate** topological order?

Comment: I mean that you can check each of the 3 additional topological orders that you listed to see if its actually a valid topological order.

Comment: I don't get your answer in your post (not comment). Regarding the comment, I have done checking and I am uncertain and would like to clarify before I misunderstand the rest of the chapter. I am new to this.

Comment: You are uncertain on the truth value of the statement "for each edge $(u,v)$ in the graph, $u$ appears before $v$ in all the orders given in the question" ?

Comment: Yes, I am uncertain

Comment: The graph has an edge $(b,a)$ and $b$ appears before $a$ in all orders.
The graph has an edge $(b,d)$ and $b$ appears before $d$ in all orders.
The graph has an edge $(a,c)$ and $a$ appears before $c$ in all orders.
The graph has an edge $(d,c)$ and $d$ appears before $c$ in all orders.
The graph has an edge $(c,e)$ and $c$ appears before $e$ in all orders.
The graph has an edge $(c,f)$ and $c$ appears before $f$ in all orders.
The graph has no more edges, therefore the statement from my previous comment is true, and all the orders in your question are valid topological orders.